# Matching Cards with Indicator Function

Tags: probability

Consider a well-shuffled deck of $n$ cards, labeled 1 through $n$.
A card is a match if the card's position in the deck matches with the card's label.
Let $X$ be the number of matches. I would like to find $E(X)$ using indicator random variable.

Let $X=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n I_j$
Where $I_j=1$ if $j^{th}$ card is a match, and $0$ otherwise.

$\textbf{My Question:}$ Why is $E(I_j)=\frac{1}{n}$?

Reference:
Blitzstein, J. K., & Hwang, J. (2014). $\textit{Introduction to probability.}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ cards in total which can be shuffled in $n!$ ways. Now, if you fix the position of $i$th card, you are left with $n-1$ cards to be placed in remaining $n-1$ places. This can be done in $(n-1)!$ ways. Therefore, the probability that $I_i=1$ is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Since $I_i$ is a Bernaulli random variable its expected value is nothing but the probability that $I_i=1$. Which answers your question.

Comment: thanks for the response!